# Unable to connect with CosmosDB

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, azure-cosmosdb, .net-6.0

I'm trying to connect a minimal API from .NET 6.0 with CosmosDB and I'm getting this error

> Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient' while attempting to activate 'AzureCS_API.db.CosmosDbService'.

As I'm new to minimal API I don't have enough experience to work with so I need a little bit of help. I'm pretty sure that I do have something else wrong so... any help is welcome

This is my `Program.cs`

```cs
var client = new TextAnalyticsClient(new Uri(Secrets.apiEndpoint), new AzureKeyCredential(Secrets.secretEndpoint));

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// COSMOSDB CONFIGURATION
static async Task<CosmosDbService> InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync(IConfigurationSection configurationSection)
{
    var account = configurationSection["Account"];
    var key = configurationSection["Key"];
    var databaseName = configurationSection["DatabaseName"];
    var containerName = configurationSection["ContainerName"];

    var client = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosClient(account, key);
    var database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync(databaseName);
    await database.Database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(containerName, "/id");
    var cosmosDbService = new CosmosDbService(client, databaseName, containerName);
    return cosmosDbService;
}

var section = builder.Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb");
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
var db = builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbService>(InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync(section).GetAwaiter().GetResult());
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICosmosDbService, CosmosDbService>();

var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", async ([FromServices] CosmosDbService db) => {});

app.MapGet("/{id}", async ([FromServices] CosmosDbService db, int id) => {});

app.MapPost("/", async (Message message, [FromServices] CosmosDbService db) => {});
```

and so on. This is my `appsettings.json`

```json
"CosmosDb": {
  "Account": "",
  "Key": ,
  "DatabaseName": "",
  "ContainerName": ""
}
```

I think it's important to point out that the `ICosmosDbService` and its implementation are just the CRUD functions.

Comment: This isn't related to minimal APIs at all. The issue is very simple, as the error message indicates: `CosmosDbService`'s constructor requires `CosmosClient` but you haven't registered that dependency with the service container.

Comment: It's undoubtedly caused by having both this line `builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICosmosDbService>(InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync(section).GetAwaiter().GetResult());` and a second registration for `ICosmosDbService` in this line `builder.Services.AddTransient<ICosmosDbService, CosmosDbService>();`

Comment: Thank you, guys. I was doing some research on StackOverflow and other resources, the problem was using the interface instead of the implementation. I removed `builder.Services.AddTransient<ICosmosDbService, CosmosDbService>();` and left this two lines `var section = builder.Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDb");
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CosmosDbService>(InitializeCosmosClientInstanceAsync(section).GetAwaiter().GetResult());`

Comment: Please avoid the CreateXXXXXIfNotExists during initialization unless you really expect the database and container to have been deleted. Bullet 13 on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/best-practice-dotnet